# using pointers to functions to create a menu-driven system

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to use pointers to functions to create a menu-driven system, but when I compile it I got a warning

```
[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type 

void (*gradeProcess[4])(int)={printArray,minimum,maximum,average};
```

I couldn't fix it, can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  STUDENTS 3
#define EXAMS 3

void printArray(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests);
void minimum(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests);
void maximum(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests);
void average(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests);

int main(void)
{
int examGrades[STUDENTS][EXAMS];
int choice;
int i,j;
void (*gradeProcess[4])(int)={printArray,minimum,maximum,average};

for(i=0;i<STUDENTS;i++){
    printf("Enter the grades of student %d:\n",i);
    for(j=0;j<EXAMS;j++){
        scanf("%d",&examGrades[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n\n0 to print array\n1 to find the lowest grade\n2 to find the highest grade\n3 to find average for each student\n4 to end program\n\n");

printf("Enter the number of operation you want to process:");
scanf("%d",&choice);

while(choice>=0 && choice<4){
    (*gradeProcess[choice])(choice);

    printf("Enter the number of operation you want to process:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
}

printf("\n\nProgram execution completed\n");

system("PAUSE");
return (0);
}

void printArray(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests)
{
printf("You chose to print array\n\n");
printf("            [0]  [1]  [2]");

for(pupils=0;pupils<STUDENTS;pupils++){
    printf("\nstudent[%d]= ",pupils);
    for(tests=0;tests<EXAMS;tests++){
        printf("%4d",grades[pupils][tests]);
    }
}
}

void minimum(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests)
{
int lowest=0;

printf("The lowest grade will be displayed");

for(pupils=0;pupils<STUDENTS;pupils++){
    for(tests=0;tests<EXAMS;tests++){
        if(lowest>grades[pupils][tests]){
            lowest=grades[pupils][tests];
        }
    }
}

printf("\nThe lowest grade is %d",lowest);
}

void maximum(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests)
{
int highest=0;

printf("The highest grade will be displayed");

for(pupils=0;pupils<STUDENTS;pupils++){
    for(tests=0;tests<EXAMS;tests++){
        if(highest>grades[pupils][tests]){
            highest=grades[pupils][tests];
        }
    }
}

printf("\nThe highest grade is %d",highest);
}

void average(const int grades[][EXAMS],int pupils,int tests)
{
int total;
double average;

printf("You chose to display average of each student\n\n");

for(pupils=0;pupils<STUDENTS;pupils++){
    printf("The average for student[%d]:",pupils);
    for(tests=0;tests<EXAMS;tests++){
        total+=grades[pupils][tests];
    }
    average=(double)total/tests;
    printf("%.2lf",average);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour, use a typedef:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(const int [][EXAMS], int, int);

//...

fptr gradeProcess[4] = { printArray, minimum, maximum, average };
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions for which you want to use function pointers all have a signature of `void foo(const int [][EXAMS], int, int)` but the function pointer you have declared is for signature `void foo(int)` due to which you are getting this warning. Modify the declarations from `void (*gradeProcess[4])(int)` to `void (*gradeProcess[4])(const int [][EXAMS], int, int)` to match the signature. The better option will be what Kerrek SB has suggested. It is  recommended you follow suggestion of `typedef`provided. Once you have done that you need to change the way you are using your function pointer. Probably you meant to use `(*gradeProcess[choice])(examGrades, STUDENTS, EXAMS);` or `(*gradeProcess[choice]) ( (const int (*)[EXAMS])examGrades, STUDENTS, EXAMS);` or  `gradeProcess[choice]( (const int (*)[EXAMS])examGrades, STUDENTS, EXAMS);`
Additionally look into the logic of initialization of lowest & highest you functions  minimum & maximum. Also in  average function you are using uninitialized variable total which should have been initialized.
Hope this helps!